# Change of char encoding in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, utf-8, character-encoding

I am working on an assignment where I need to XOR the bits of each char of a given text. For example, weird char's like '��'.

When trying to save, Eclipse prompts that "Some characters cannot be mapped with Cp1252...", after which I can choose to save as UTF-8.

My knowledge of character encoding is quite fuzzy; wouldn't saving to UTF-8 change the bits? If so, how may I instead work with the original message (original bits) to XOR them and do my assignment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Java in this answer.

The file encoding only changes how the data is represented in the file. When you read the file again (using the correct encoding) it will converted back to Unicode in your String so the program will see the same bits.

Encoding Cp1252 can only represent a small number of characters (less than 256) compared to the 113,021 characters in Unicode 7 all of which can be encoded with UTF-8.